# Will Joomla JAuthentication obey the user plugins?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, authentication

I do a custom PHP page that allows member to validate their Joomla login credentials.  Following is the code.

```
    $credentials = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password);

    $options = array();

    $authenticate = JAuthentication::getInstance();
    $response = $authenticate->authenticate($credentials, $options);
```

Will this code obey the Joomla user plugin events.  For example If I write a plugin that uses 'onUserAfterLogin' will the above code call the plugin hook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

To trigger plugin events, you should use:

```
$credentials = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password);

$options = array();

$app = JApplicationCms::getInstance('site');
$result = $app->login($credentials, $options); // boolean true, if login suceeded
```

But as you can guess, this will do real login. So user will be logged in. If you want user to still be logged out, just use below code after success from `$result`.

```
if($result){
    $app->logout();
}
```